# How can a style be set on a specific polygon using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, select, style

Using a polygon id, I want to highlight a polygon, while the mouse is outside of the map area. I can identify the polygon using the following approach:

```
x = 53;
for(i=0; i<vector_layer.features.length; i++){
        y = vector_layer.features[i].attributes.id
        if(x == y){
            vector_layer.features[i].style = ??
        }           
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to highlight the polygon even though I know which one it is. I have previously defined a style for when the mouse hovers over the polygon and it is `selected`, but I don't know how to apply this style to the chosen polygon.

Comment: how are you planning to select the polygon ID ?

Comment: In this case, I know what the polygon id is through user selection, outside of the map.

Comment: check this link out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832029/how-to-select-a-feature-programmatically-on-a-vector-layer-in-openlayers/8840641

Comment: Thanks @GlennPlas - that link pointed out that selection can be done using `selectFeature.select(this.vlayer.features[i]);` when `selectFeature` is defined as a control. Not sure if you can move your comment to answer, but I could mark as the answer if so.

Comment: It will be a short answer, but It's good to be able to close a question, GIS has a lower answer rate than SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution to this problem can be extracted from [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832029/how-to-select-a-feature-programmatically-on-a-vector-layer-in-openlayers/8840641).  That link points out that selection can be done using:

```
selectFeature.select(this.vlayer.features[i]);
```

when selectFeature is defined as a control.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code but you have to redraw your layer after changing its style. Put this line into your loop:

```
vector_layer.redraw();
```

i hope it helps you...